# Did the Roman army have more servants than soldiers?

Tags: history, military, ancient-rome

In [one of his essays](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/DevelopmentAbstraction.html) Joel Spolsky (co-founder of Stack Exchange) wrote:

> [...] the Roman army had a ratio of four
>   servants for every soldier.

Is this true?

Comment: (http://bmcr.brynmawr.edu/1999/1999-11-01.html): The other main group, the calones, were slave servants, possibly state owned, and by the late Republic usually armed and sometimes organised under the command of galearii, leaders whose name seems to have derived from the wearing of a helmet. R. suggests a soldier to servant ratio of 4:1, but this is conjectural and in reality the ratio may have varied considerably

Comment: @belisarius Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Are random blog posts "notable"?

Comment: (also, this definitely would get a more expert answer on [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions))

Comment: @DVK I don't have any clues about how "notable" that post is, and that's the reason I posted it as a comment.

Comment: @belisarius -  I was referring to JoS blog, not the edu link you posted. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @DVK :) Don't worry. Anyway, although me being far from an expert in Roman history I don't believe the composition ratios of the "Roman army" were kept the same along its history.